# How to filter out rows based on specific column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame. I need to select `Score` for those entries that have column's `Ind` values equal to 0.

```
Score = df[df['Ind'] == 0]['Score']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc`:

```
Score = df.loc[df['Ind']==0, 'Score']
```

So we pass the boolean condition as the first param and then col of interest.

The boolean condition generates a boolean mask that is used to mask the index against so will only return those rows.

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#selection-by-label) give various examples of indexing